# Binding model inside model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add model inside model but it is showing {{filterText}} instead of showing text.

Below is my text which will brief how i am trying:

```
$scope.filterText = "rooms";  //text will changed by user when ever he will require
$scope.items = [{"id":"1","title":"10 {{item.filterText}}","filterText":"care"},{"id":"2","title":"5 {{item.filterText}}","filterText":"rooms"},{"id":"3","title":"8 {{item.filterText}}","filterText":"Take"}];
```

In html page:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
Title : {{item.title}}
</div>
```

Right now i am getting result as:

> Title : 10 {{item.filterText}}
>
> Title : 5 {{item.filterText}}
>
> Title : 8 {{item.filterText}}

But i need:

> Title : 10 care
>
> Title : 5 rooms
>
> Title : 8 Take

I am struggling to achieve. but i am not able to achieve it how to do this?

Comment: Yes, the `{{ }}` show a compiled expression. So you need Angular to compile that for you. The best solution would be to make a directive that you repeat instead!!

Comment: Thanks @Callum Linington, can u suggest me some example for it

Comment: Can I just ask what you are trying to achieve, is it a format type operation where the source code will specify a format for the text to be outputted in?  I wonder how the angular js expression has leaked into your business object

Comment: I have one input in modal which will allow user to add a title, so user can add filtertext before or after or in center or in anywhere, for example if user need to add 10 {{filtertext}} or {{filtertext}} 8 or he can type 10 per {{filtertext}} charges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , its working . Use `$interpolate` , [link](http://excellencenodejsblog.com/angularjs-compile-parse-interpolate/)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$interpolate) {
$scope.filterText = "rooms";  //text will changed by user when ever he will require
$scope.items = $scope.items = [{"id":"1","title":"10 {{item.filterText}}","filterText":"care"},{"id":"2","title":"5 {{item.filterText}}","filterText":"rooms"},{"id":"3","title":"8 {{item.filterText}}","filterText":"Take"}];;


$scope.compiledItems = [];
for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++){
  $scope.item = {};
  $scope.item.filterText = $scope.items[i].filterText;
  var text = $interpolate($scope.items[i].title)($scope); 
  $scope.compiledItems.push(text); 
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in compiledItems">
      Title : {{item}}
     </div> 
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rejs, for your answer. i have modified the question little bit and then this approach is not working for me any help? as i any user can change fitertext position when ever he like. he can place left or right or center of some text

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$scope.filterText = "rooms";  //text will changed by user when ever he will require
$scope.items = [{"id":"1","title":"10"},{"id":"2","title":"5"},{"id":"3","title":"8"}];

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
Title : {{item.title}} {{filterText}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Durgesh, but this is not what i need to do.

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('controller', function($scope, $interpolate) {
  $scope.filterText = "rooms";
  $scope.items = [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": compile("10 {{filterText}}")
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "title": compile("5 {{filterText}}")
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "title": compile("8 {{filterText}}")
  }];

  function compile(text) {
    return $interpolate(text)($scope);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    Title : {{item.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

What you want is to *interpolate* the `title`.
You can you `$interpolate` service and interpolate a given expression using a specified scope.

Example: `$interpolate('hello {{user}}')($scope);`, where user is `$scope.user = 'someone'`

Answer (score 0):

One another way of doing the same thing. Here you put a watch on the item what you want to watch and make changes to your object every time it changes. It is especially good if your objects are being populated from back end.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []).constant('_', window._)
  // use in views, ng-repeat="x in _.range(3)"
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope._ = window._;
  });

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.filterText = 'rooms';
  $scope.resultsSample = [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "10"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "5"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "8"
  }];

  $scope.$watch('filterText', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(oldVal + '  ' + newVal);
    $scope.results = $scope.resultsSample;

    _.forEach($scope.results, function(value, key) {
      if (value.title.indexOf(oldVal) == -1 || oldVal == '') {
        value.title = value.title + ' ' + newVal;
      } else {
        value.title = value.title.replace(oldVal, newVal);
      }
    });
  }, true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type='textbox' name='myFilter' ng-model='filterText' />
  <div ng-repeat='result in results'>
    Title : {{result.title}}
  </div>
</body>
```